# Error de: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Host desconocido. En asp.net

Tags: asp.net, websocket, signalr, asp.net-mvc-4

Estimados, junto con saludarle quería hacerle la siguiente pregunta al problema que me surgió:

resulta que estoy haciendo unas pruebas para trabajar con SignalR, en el cual los resultados son exitosos cuando hago las pruebas en localhost, pero cuando publico al servidor de producción, me sale el siguiente error:

**Host desconocido
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Host desconocido**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La forma como empezé fue la siguiente:

Primero descargue los paquetes de signalR

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Después cree el archivo Startup:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;

[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(MvcMasterPrueba.Startup))]

namespace MvcMasterPrueba
{
   public class Startup
   {
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        //ConfigureAuth(app);
        app.MapSignalR();
    }
  }
}
```

archivo hub:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;

namespace MvcMasterPrueba
{
public class MyHub : Hub
{
    public void Send(string name, string message)
    {
        Clients.All.broadcastMessage(name, message);
    }

    public void BroadcastMessageToAll(string nombreImpresora, String divHTML)
    {
        //Clients.All.newMessageReceived(message);
        Clients.All.imprimeDiv(nombreImpresora, divHTML);

    }
    public void BroadcastMessageToPrinter(string nombreImpresora, String divHTML)
    {
        Clients.All.imprimeDiv(nombreImpresora, divHTML);
    }

    public void JoinAGroup(string group)
    {
        Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, group);
    }

    public void RemoveFromAGroup(string group)
    {
        Groups.Remove(Context.ConnectionId, group);
    }

  }
}
```

Lo extraño que al publicar en el servidor, me sale el error, les agradecería mucho su ayuda, si alguien tiene alguna idea, sera bienvenida su opinión. Desde ya gracias.
Otra información importante, al intentar loguearme, me sale el error, es decir en esta parte:

```
public ActionResult Acceder(string User, string Pass)
    {
        string estado = "0";
        string ip = "";
        string db = "";
        string user = "";
        string pass = "";
        string password = "";
        string sql = "SELECT ip,db,user,CONVERT(AES_DECRYPT(`pass`,'1234444444') USING UTF8) AS pass,password " +
                     "FROM usuarios " +
                     "WHERE email='" + User + "' and password='" + Pass + "' limit 1";
        conexion.conectar();
        MySqlDataAdapter datos = new MySqlDataAdapter(sql, conexion.conlogin);
        conexion.cerrar();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        datos.Fill(dt);
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            ip = row[0].ToString();
            db = row[1].ToString();
            user = row[2].ToString();
            pass = row[3].ToString();
            password = row[4].ToString();
        }
        if (Pass == password)
        {
            Session["Session_User"] = User;
            Session["ip"] = ip;
            Session["db"] = db;
            Session["user"] = user;
            Session["pass"] = pass;
            estado = "1";
            Session["ss_nro_caja"] = obtieneNroCaja();
        }
        switch (estado)
        {
            case "0":
                ViewData["Mensaje"] = "Usuario o Password invalido..!!";
                return View("Login");
            case "1":
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(User, false);
                return RedirectToAction("Home", "Acceso");
            default:
                return View("Login");
        }
    }
```

Se supone que cuando voy en esta parte, sucede el error:

```
    case "1":
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(User, false);
                return RedirectToAction("Principal", "Acceso");
```

Comment: Saludos Danilo, en tu server, en las característica, activa WebSockets

Comment: No he usado nunca SignalR con lo que no estoy seguro pero...tiene pinta de error al resolver una dns

Comment: Edite la pregunta, puse mas información

Comment: @fredyfx 
disculpa, como lo haría?

Comment: así: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-websocket-protocol-support

Comment: @fredyfx
hice lo que sale en la documentación, pero sigo con el error

Comment: ¿Reiniciaste el server?

Comment: @fredyfx
si, reinciado

Comment: @aplique la parte de habiltar con el check WebSocket Protocol

Comment: @fredyfx, lo extraño del error que se de después de loguearme

Comment: @Danilo ¿Qué tienes en acceso?

Comment: @fredyfx , puse el codigo en la pregunta, en la edición

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70514/discussion-between-fredyfx-and-danilo).

Comment: Encontre la causa del error, es por la linea 
System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(Request.ServerVariables["remote_addr"]).HostName

quería obtener el nombre del equipo en el uno se encuentra y no del servidor, me gustaría saber ahora por cual codigo cambiar